# Unhandled IOException in PerformIOCompletionCallback

Tags: .net, asynchronous, winsock, ioexception, unhandled-exception

While stopping a process I caught the following exception with the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event. Latest .NET 4.0 on Windows 7.

```
IsTerminating flag:True
Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set()
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Anyone know what causes this?

Comment: It is caused by an invalid handle.  Avoid the duh comment by carefully describing what "stopping a process" means.

Comment: Correction: reanalysis of the logs shows that it happened more or less out of the blue (not during a shutdown sequence).
I know it's a broad question. What I'm trying to find out is what kind of event could trigger this exception? For example, does it have to be something internal to this process?

Comment: Could be anything but this kind of problem tends to be induced when a process consumes its quota of handles due to a handle leak.  Visible in TaskMgr.exe, Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick Handles.

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled exceptions in `PerformIOCompletionCallback` could occur if the socket was disposed while there were outstanding async IO operations.
Once the operation completes, it would attempt to access members of the disposed socket, which isn't in the mood to play nicely.

A memory dump, created during this exception, could shed some light here. [This blog post](http://www.liranchen.com/2014/08/unhandled-exceptions-in.html) should help clear things up in this regard.